# Mark last data point in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I tell pgfplots to only put a mark on the (first and) last data point of a scatter/mesh plot? I can use `mark indices` to select the first, but how to select the last point without knowing a priori, how many points there will be?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [
                mesh,
                mark=o,
                mark indices={1},
                mark size=1.5pt,
                mark options={draw=red},
                point meta={\thisrow{n}}
            ] table {trace.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The file `trace.dat` looks like this, but much longer:

```
x y n r
3 -1 17 27
1 -2 18 24
-1 -3 19 45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{trace.dat}
x y n r
3 -1 17 27
1 -2 18 24
-1 -3 19 45
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{trace.dat}\datatable   
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [
                mesh,
                mark=o,
                mark indices={1,\rownum},
                mark size=1.5pt,
                mark options={draw=red},
                point meta={\thisrow{n}}
            ] table {trace.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]